# Architectural Constraints In Java

Tags: java, maven, architecture

I want to be sure that my project doesn't contain unnecessary dependencies among packages. For example, I want to be sure that the project has layered structure. I.e. model is below everything, business logic depend on model, view dependes on business logic and model. Each of the layers is place in its own package.

Could you recommend any, preferably open source tools which allow me to specify these constraint and check them as a part of continuous integration?

P.S. I know that I can separate the project in separate maven modules. Unfortunately, my real world case is more complex than 3-layered system. If I used maven modules, I would have several dozens of quite small modules.

Comment: what's wrong with several dozens of small modules?

Comment: @yegor256 I don't want to create a module per packge. IMHO, it's overkill.

Comment: There may still be a happy medium between a large number of small modules and one module per package.  Modules ought to be small enough to thoroughly test, but large enough to contain a logical unit.

Comment: @jordan002 Yes, there should be. However, maven modules doesn't allow me to enforce some kinds of constraints. For example, some packages shouldn't be used from external modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Structure101](http://structure101.com) lets you define your layers visually as cells in [Architecture Diagrams](http://structure101.com/help/java/structure101/intro_software-architecture.html) which map to the physical code and check conformance. These diagrams are visible in the developers' IDEs and generate edit time warnings if the layering rules are violated. It is also possible to break/report the build during CI. [SonarJ](http://www.hello2morrow.com/products/sonarj) and [Lattix](http://www.lattix.com/) are other tools for visual dependency control.

Comment: Structure101 is the closest tool to what I wanted. Unfortunately, it's not open source.

Answer (score 6):

Although I am not sure if it is possible to enforce a build failure on layer dependency violation, there is at least a tool that can check and visualize these layers: [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/). You can integrate it with your maven and jenkins builds as well as with eclipse (and maybe other IDEs).

Sonar features a [dependency matrix view](http://www.sonarsource.org/sonar-2-0-in-screenshots/) which visualized the interdependencies of packages.

EDIT: it seems to be possible to configure sonar to force the build to fail triggered by a violation: the [build breaker plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin)

Comment: Can also use Sonar to create Architecture rules which when combined with build breaker can trigger build failures: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Architecture+Rule+Engine

Answer (score 4):

This is a very valid question, since lots of projects enforce dependencies through Maven modules, which is a huge waste of productivity and flexibility.

After spending a lot of time researching on this subject I could recommend two tools:

- Macker (http://innig.net/macker/) it has Maven plugin
- Classycle (http://classycle.sourceforge.net/) it has to be plugged-in using Ant

Both tools are not evolving much last years, but are working well. Macker has XML-based syntax, but Classycle has neat DSL. Classycle is more high-level specialized tool and has concept of layers. These tools allow you to enforce strict barriers between packages and certain class types. This tools should be configured in build process to fail upon any constraint immediately.

Check the layering example here (http://innig.net/macker/example/layering/src/macker.xml) and here (http://classycle.sourceforge.net/ddf.html#layer).

There is still a niche for a good open source tool, which would hook into compiler and would give you errors while you are in IDE rather than in build tool. [Structure101](http://structure101.com/) is much more feature rich, but also heavy and relies on Eclipse plugin.

**Update**

These is also [JQAssistant](http://jqassistant.org), which is very powerful, but can take quite some time to learn and setup.

Comment: A maven plugin is also available for classycle https://github.com/hcoles/classycle-maven-plugin

Answer (score 3):

[JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) can analyze your code base and provide you the metrics you are looking for. Three main metrics you are looking for are **Afferent Couplings**, **Efferent Couplings** and **Package Dependency Cycles**.

[Architexa](http://www.architexa.com/) is another tool that might of help here.

Comment: JDepend just analyze dependencies. It doesn't lead to build failure in case of incorrect dependencies. Currently, I use IntelliJ DSM feature to analyze such dependencies.

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov Agree but you can define rules in Sonar to faild the build for that. I didn't include Sonar in my post as it was already mentioned by Kostja. We use the build breaker plugin at our work to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Checkstyle to implement "customized checks". See it to learn more:
http://saturnnetwork.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/ultimate-architecture-enforcement-prevent-code-violations-at-code-commit-time/

I did not try it myself but I think it is not difficult to implement and it's free.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools that can help you enforce your layered architecture and dependency restrictions in general. These tools are language specific. 
If you're using Java, I can suggest creating your custom checks using checkstyle.

I authored the text Anton referred to ([Ultimate Architecture Enforcement](http://saturnnetwork.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/ultimate-architecture-enforcement-prevent-code-violations-at-code-commit-time/)). It's based on our own successful experience. Custom checks can be integrated to the IDE (e.g., Eclipse), can be integrated to your continuous integration tool (e.g., Jenkins), and as the last resort to prevent violations can be executed automatically as a pre-commit verification on Subversion. 
The custom checks themselves are written in Java using the checkstyle API.