# Can I use AspectJ / AOP to install compile time access rules between Java classes beyond the normal visibility rules?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, compile-time, access-rights

We are currently working on setting up a service layer oriented structure, persistence manager as the lowest layer, service classes on top. The persistence managers would do all the basic things on entities like create, update, find one, find all, filter, sort etc.
The services would contain the minimal viable business logic for the entity.

We would now want to implement the rule that managers must not access other managers, services need to perform the work across managers.
The Java type system with its visibility rules do not provide for this, though - private/protected is valid globally, not just for other managers, the managers need to be visible to other services.

So we though about AOP that would surely enable access restrictions between classes, but we would like the rules to be considered compile time, not run time.
It seems - not had the possibility to look into this in depth - that AspectJ provides for compile time AOP, but does that include compile time access restrictions between classes as described above?

Any hint on this would help us to decide quickly whether to pursue that path at all or not.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459657/architectural-constraints-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use AspectJ compile-time weaving, indeed. Take a look at the `declare warning` and `declare error` statements which are described [here](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-declare.html#warnings-and-errors) and [here](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-declare.html). For a more precise answer including actual aspect code I would need to know your package  and maybe class naming structure.